Stieltjes constants limit definition
I search for the connection between Stieltjes constant definition as Laurent development coefficients of Riemann zeta at s=1 (asuming simple pole there):
$$\zeta(s+1) = \frac{1}{s} + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{\gamma_k}{k!}}(-s)^k$$
and its definition according a logartithm powers infinite sum:
$$\gamma_k=\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}{\big[\sum_{n=1}^{m}{\frac{(\ln(n))^k}{n}}-\frac{(\ln(m))^{k+1}}{k+1}}\big]$$
I understand they are related to zeta function derivatives at s=1 but no clear way to calculate them as pole makes all derivatives at this point dificult to calculate as diverge.
Could you advise a way to avoid this divergences?
Thanks in advance

Sorry but I saw following paper from J.Lagarias that provide a proof at page 32:
http://arxiv.org/pdf/1303.1856v6.pdf
